# map thread-safety - is it enought to wrap the methods?

Tags: java, thread-safety

is this class threadsafe ? or do I have to add synchronization on the map ?

```
public class MapTest {

    private static final TreeMap<String,String> map = new TreeMap<>();

    public static final synchronized String get(String key){
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public static final synchronized void put(String key,String value){
         map.put(key,value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Variables can't have the `synchronized` keyword, if that's what you're suggesting. As it is, the class is thread safe.

Comment: I can use a ConcurrentMap https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html

Comment: It would be easier if you were to wrap your `TreeMap<String, String>` with `Map#synchronizedMap` when initializing it.

Comment: This is mutable shared state.  It has to be synchronized.

Comment: @duffymo It is synchronized.

Comment: A ConcurrentSkipListMap gives you a thread safe, sorted map.

Comment: `Map.syncrhonizedMap()` and using a class from `java.util.concurrent` are both good ideas.  I want to point out that your class is "thread safe" but there still may be issues with atomicity.  For example, if you want to test (get) then add (put) a value as a single atomic operation, you still require extra code.  That sort of interference problem is not solved by adding the `synchronized` keyword.  `java.util.concurrent` classes have method like `putIfAbsent` that help with this sort of issue.

Comment: @markspace `Collections.synchronizedMap()` will synchronize around `putIfAbsent()` and other similar operations, making them effectively atomic.